# Почему не работает -run с подтестами?

Tags: golang, юнит-тесты

Есть два теста, `TestFoo/cache` и `TestFoo/nocache`. Я пытаюсь запустить только первый вот так:

```sh
$ go test -run "TestFoo/cache"
```

Но запускаются оба теста:

```
--- FAIL: TestFoo (2.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestFoo/cache (1.00s)
    --- PASS: TestFoo/nocache (1.00s)
```

Почему? Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем документацию:

```sh
$ go help testflag
```

```
(…)
        -run regexp
            Run only those tests and examples matching the regular expression.
            For tests, the regular expression is split by unbracketed slash (/)
            characters into a sequence of regular expressions, and each part
            of a test's identifier must match the corresponding element in
            the sequence, if any. Note that possible parents of matches are
            run too, so that -run=X/Y matches and runs and reports the result
            of all tests matching X, even those without sub-tests matching Y,
            because it must run them to look for those sub-tests.
(…)
```

То есть, `-run "TestFoo/cache"` воспринимается как команда «запустить всё внитри тестов, подходящих под регексп `TestFoo`, что подходит под регексп `cache`», поэтому `nocache` тоже запускается. Верно использовать что-то типа такого:

```sh
$ go test -run "^TestFoo\$/^cache\$"
```